Two VRFs on the same VLAN?
I am using Debian and trying to configure /etc/network/interfaces in a way that two VRFs use the same VLANs. I need the two VRFs to create two BGP routers, but I also need to share the same VLAN between them because only one VLAN is configured at my provider router. Is it possible to do so? As an example, I want to have router1-vrf on vmbr0.1550 and router2-vrf also on vmbr0.1550.
